# set permission for sendBroadcast function android

Tags: android

I want to use context.sendBroadcast(intent, receiverPermission); in my application,
so please any body help me how to set receiver permission in function as well as manifest file

Answer (score 4):

In your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.permission.RECEIVE_MY_BROADCAST" />
```